# GCC: list a statically linked libraries

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, ld, static-linking

That's the question. Basically my problem is that I am trying to compile an app for ARM with an options `-fsanitize=address -static-libasan` (cool thing for debugging a wrong pointers and etc.). This compiles fine directly to executable file, but doesn't work for compiling from an object files. Ofc I found that the static lib is `libasan.a`; anyway when I am trying to link everything from an object file, it says about a bunch of an undefined references in «pthread» and some functions whose lib-owner I didn't even managed to find.

So, I just want to compile a file with `-fsanitize=address -static-libasan` and see which a libraries were linked statically, so that I could later do it from an object file.

Comment: _"...it says about a bunch of an undefined references in «pthread» ..."_ Tried adding `-pthread` to the compiler and linker options?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ of course.

Comment: If you use "a" before a noun, you can't put the noun in plural. "a libraries", "a wrong pointers", "an object files" – all of these are equally nonsensical.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant okay. Have I another problems in my spelling?

Comment: Okay, just if anyone would appear here because of libasan mentioned I'll leave here also an answer how did I finally managed to link it statically from an object file. It was nontrivial, but I managed it to work with the options «-Wl,-Bstatic -lasan -Wl,-Bdynamic -lpthread -ldl» being added to GCC's command line for link time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An executable stores no trace of any static libraries it pulled object files from. Mostly these libraries are explicitly specified when linking, though. The compiler only pulls in a few standard static libraries. For [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) you can see various information including the actual command line passed to the linker using the `-v` option (it seems some implementations want to use `--verbose` and for the linker `-Wl,--verbose`). This output should show all implicitly linked libraries like `-lgcc` and `-lstdc++`.

Note that you should link using the language specific frontend and the same compiler flags as when compiling. Your problem description sounds as if you use `-pthread` with `g++` when compiling but you tried to link using `gcc` without the `-pthread` flags (there are a few different threading related flags; from the description it is impossible to tell which one was used).

Just to deal with the insults, here is an example output when using the `-v` option on my computer:

```
ThreadGard:stackoverflow kuehl$ cat hello.cpp 
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "hello, world\n";
  return 0;
}
ThreadGard:stackoverflow kuehl$ g++ -v -static hello.cpp
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/gcc-4.9.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Configured with: ../gcc-4.9.2/configure --prefix=/opt/gcc-4.9.2 --with-gmp=/opt/gcc-infrastructure --with-mpfr=/opt/gcc-infrastructure --enable-decimal-float=bid --enable-lto --enable-languages=c,c++
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-mmacosx-version-min=10.9.4' '-v' '-static' '-mtune=core2'
 /opt/gcc-4.9.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2/cc1plus -quiet -v -D__STATIC__ hello.cpp -quiet -dumpbase hello.cpp -mmacosx-version-min=10.9.4 -mtune=core2 -auxbase hello -version -o /var/folders/b_/64plfvs936v5ylx36qwc8rg00000gp/T//ccrt7fXS.s
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.9.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.9.2, GMP version 5.0.5, MPFR version 3.1.1, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/gcc-4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /opt/gcc-4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2/../../../../include/c++/4.9.2
 /opt/gcc-4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2/../../../../include/c++/4.9.2/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
 /opt/gcc-4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2/../../../../include/c++/4.9.2/backward
 /opt/gcc-4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2/include
 /usr/local/include
 /opt/gcc-4.9.2/include
 /opt/gcc-4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2/include-fixed
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks
 /Library/Frameworks
End of search list.
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.9.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.9.2, GMP version 5.0.5, MPFR version 3.1.1, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: fea0def5b69cf8ae349b2f1faf4b1d23
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-mmacosx-version-min=10.9.4' '-v' '-static' '-mtune=core2'
 as -arch x86_64 -force_cpusubtype_ALL -static -o /var/folders/b_/64plfvs936v5ylx36qwc8rg00000gp/T//ccPF77oR.o /var/folders/b_/64plfvs936v5ylx36qwc8rg00000gp/T//ccrt7fXS.s
COMPILER_PATH=/opt/gcc-4.9.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2/:/opt/gcc-4.9.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2/:/opt/gcc-4.9.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/:/opt/gcc-4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2/:/opt/gcc-4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/
LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/gcc-4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2/:/opt/gcc-4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2/../../../:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-mmacosx-version-min=10.9.4' '-v' '-static' '-mtune=core2'
 /opt/gcc-4.9.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2/collect2 -static -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.9.4 -weak_reference_mismatches non-weak -o a.out -lcrt0.o -L/opt/gcc-4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2 -L/opt/gcc-4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2/../../.. /var/folders/b_/64plfvs936v5ylx36qwc8rg00000gp/T//ccPF77oR.o /opt/gcc-4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2/../../../libstdc++.a -no_compact_unwind -no_pie -lgcc_eh -lgcc -v
collect2 version 4.9.2
/usr/bin/ld -static -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.9.4 -weak_reference_mismatches non-weak -o a.out -lcrt0.o -L/opt/gcc-4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2 -L/opt/gcc-4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2/../../.. /var/folders/b_/64plfvs936v5ylx36qwc8rg00000gp/T//ccPF77oR.o /opt/gcc-4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2/../../../libstdc++.a -no_compact_unwind -no_pie -lgcc_eh -lgcc -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-241.9
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7m armv7em
Library search paths:
    /opt/gcc-4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2
    /opt/gcc-4.9.2/lib
    /usr/lib
    /usr/local/lib
Framework search paths:
    /Library/Frameworks/
    /System/Library/Frameworks/
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

There are not all static libraries installed to make it actually link. However, that's besides the point as the output clearly lists the linker invocation:

> /usr/bin/ld -static -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.9.4 -weak_reference_mismatches non-weak -o a.out -lcrt0.o -L/opt/gcc-4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2 -L/opt/gcc-4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2/../../.. /var/folders/b_/64plfvs936v5ylx36qwc8rg00000gp/T//ccPF77oR.o /opt/gcc-4.9.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/4.9.2/../../../libstdc++.a -no_compact_unwind -no_pie -lgcc_eh **-lgcc** -v

(with some emphasis added to make it easier for readers - it seems to be necessary)

Comment: That doesn't answer at all. I don't want to take an information from a compiled binary about a static libs, I just want an option that shows me a statically linked libs when I am compiling. E.g. try to create a simple «helloworld.cpp», and compile it with `g++  -static-libgcc helloworld.cpp`. How do you know what the libraries exactly was linked statically? *(in the example it is obviously `libgcc`, but in my question this doesn't work — I already found the `libasan`, and there still a libraries remains that seems to be affected by `-static-libasan`)*

Comment: Which part of the `-v` option didn't I mention exactly?

Comment:  Actually, Dietmar Kühl did you tried it by yourself? I don't see from an output even a hint that the `libgcc` from a little example in my previous comment is linked statically.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: there was no need to do so as I know how the output looks like: I'm using it sufficiently often (one of the perils of working on a standard C++ library just for personal entertainment). See my update to the question, if necessary just at the last quote with emphasis.

Comment: Hm… That's interesting… You know, for some reason I have no from the output of the `-v` option nor the `somelib.a`, nor a mention about `ld`… [that's what I have](http://pastebin.com/scN6m94a)

Comment: Btw, I guess you wrongly understood the smile. I wasn't laughing on you, I laughed from your irony in the second comment ☺ Okay, I'll seek for something like «more verbose» for gcc; if I find, I'll add it to your post.

Comment: If you use mingw you may need to use `--verbose` and/or `-Wl,--verbose` (the `-Wl,xxx` passes the option `xxx` to the linker). I have never worked on non-POSIX systems where `-v` doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, the `-Wl,--verbose` does the trick! Thank you very much. Please, add it to the answer. Btw, I'm using Kubuntu, that is `g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2` the compiler with not a very verbose «verbose mode».

Comment: So there was a part of `-v` which was absent - interesting... Since this is actually a gcc option, including the linker invocation, it strikes me as add that it won't show all the information. Anyway, I have added the options.